# php - merge 3 or more arrays without replacing same keys alternating values

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I need to merge 3 arrays that have identical keys. The result must be one array contains alternating values of the 3 arrays.

Example

```
$array1 = array(
   array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fewf", "name"=>"bbb"),
   array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fr43", "name"=>"ccc"),
   array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fewf", "name"=>"ddd")
);

$array2 = array(
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"are5", "name"=>"ddd"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"q23q", "name"=>"eee"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"g55h", "name"=>"off"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"r3r3", "name"=>"bgf"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"f333", "name"=>"1qa")
);

$array3 = array(
   array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"bv33", "name"=>"ggg"),
   array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"nh44", "name"=>"hhh"),
   array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"tt12", "name"=>"iii")
);
```

------------------------------------- RESULT ARRAY must be alternate.

```
$array_merged = array(
   array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fewf", "name"=>"bbb"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"are5", "name"=>"ddd"),
   array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"bv33", "name"=>"ggg"),
   array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fr43", "name"=>"ccc"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"q23q", "name"=>"eee"),
   array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"nh44", "name"=>"hhh"),
   array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fewf", "name"=>"ddd"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"g55h", "name"=>"off"),
   array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"tt12", "name"=>"iii"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"r3r3", "name"=>"bgf"),
   array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"f333", "name"=>"1qa")
);
```

How could achieve this? Having the final array adding each array in a alternate way?

**--------------------- UPDATE**

I have tried doing the following:

```
$new = array();
for ($i=0; $i < $array2; $i++) {
   $new[] = $array1[$i];
   $new[] = $array2[$i];
   $new[] = $array3[$i];
}
```

However, the result gives me empty arrays when the index of the other finishes.

Comment: `$array2` have been overwritten in your code, why?

Comment: sorry my mistake .. fixed it.

Comment: I guess, it's not just about merging arrays, it's about ordering merged sequence in even order `facebook - twitter - instagram`, right?

Comment: Yes @RomanPerekhrest that is right! And If an array is shorter that the other the result does not have to merge empty arrays

Comment: ok, I have a solution for your current particular input, but what if there would be a big difference in size between the arrays? For ex.: $array1 has 3 items, $array2 has 7 items, $array3 has 12 items, what should be the result for such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing around and have come up with a flexible solution that will work for as many arrays as you want along with varying amounts of items:

```
// Group arrays in a containing array for processing
$groupedArrays = array($array1, $array2, $array3);

$maxArrayItems = max(array_map(function($array) {
    return count($array);
}, $groupedArrays));

$new = array();

// Loop through the amount of times required for the largest array
for ($i=0; $i < $maxArrayItems; $i++) {

    // Loop through for each array in the group of arrays
    for($j=0; $j < count($groupedArrays); $j++) {

        if(isset($groupedArrays[$j][$i])) {
            $new[] = $groupedArrays[$j][$i];    
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any extra arrays just add them to the `$groupedArrays` array and they'll be handled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Woo!! Thank you so much.. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$new = array();
$maxval = max(count($array1),count($array2),count($array3));
for ($i=0; $i < $maxval; $i++) {
if(array_key_exists($i, $array1)) $new[] = $array1[$i];
if(array_key_exists($i, $array2)) $new[] = $array2[$i];
if(array_key_exists($i, $array3)) $new[] = $array3[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

```
>>> $array1 = array(
...    array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fewf", "name"=>"bbb"),
...    array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fr43", "name"=>"ccc"),
...    array("social"=>"facebook", "id"=>"fewf", "name"=>"ddd")
... );
=> [
     [
       "social" => "facebook",
       "id" => "fewf",
       "name" => "bbb",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "facebook",
       "id" => "fr43",
       "name" => "ccc",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "facebook",
       "id" => "fewf",
       "name" => "ddd",
     ],
   ]
>>> 
>>> $array2 = array(
...    array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"are5", "name"=>"ddd"),
...    array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"q23q", "name"=>"eee"),
...    array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"g55h", "name"=>"off"),
...    array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"r3r3", "name"=>"bgf"),
...    array("social"=>"twitter", "id"=>"f333", "name"=>"1qa")
... );
=> [
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "are5",
       "name" => "ddd",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "q23q",
       "name" => "eee",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "g55h",
       "name" => "off",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "r3r3",
       "name" => "bgf",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "f333",
       "name" => "1qa",
     ],
   ]
>>> 
>>> $array3 = array(
...    array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"bv33", "name"=>"ggg"),
...    array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"nh44", "name"=>"hhh"),
...    array("social"=>"instagram", "id"=>"tt12", "name"=>"iii")
... );
=> [
     [
       "social" => "instagram",
       "id" => "bv33",
       "name" => "ggg",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "instagram",
       "id" => "nh44",
       "name" => "hhh",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "instagram",
       "id" => "tt12",
       "name" => "iii",
     ],
   ]
>>> array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3)
=> [
     [
       "social" => "facebook",
       "id" => "fewf",
       "name" => "bbb",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "facebook",
       "id" => "fr43",
       "name" => "ccc",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "facebook",
       "id" => "fewf",
       "name" => "ddd",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "are5",
       "name" => "ddd",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "q23q",
       "name" => "eee",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "g55h",
       "name" => "off",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "r3r3",
       "name" => "bgf",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "twitter",
       "id" => "f333",
       "name" => "1qa",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "instagram",
       "id" => "bv33",
       "name" => "ggg",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "instagram",
       "id" => "nh44",
       "name" => "hhh",
     ],
     [
       "social" => "instagram",
       "id" => "tt12",
       "name" => "iii",
     ],
   ]
```

When using, take special care with the following notes from manual:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.